# Serpentine Sorting a Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to find a way to do a special type of sorting in python on a pandas dataframe: serpentine sorting.

Here is a brief description of serpentine sorting:

Serpentine sorting reverses the sort order as each boundary is crossed for higher-level sorting variables, thus helping ensure that adjacent records are similar with respect to as many sorting variables as possible.

Below is an example of serpentine sorting using three variables, each with three categories (low, medium, and high). The sorting order is reversed during sorting of Variable 2 within categories of Variable 1 and again during sorting of Variable 3 within categories of Variable 2, so that adjacent records are similar
with respect to all three variables.

[An example of serpentine sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pO1W.png)

When I am able to work in SAS, I use a SAS procedure (Proc Survey Select) to do serpentine sorting:

```
proc surveyselect data=&outfile sort=serp method=seqrate=1;
 
/* Grouping variables*/
 strata &class;
 
 /* Sort Varaibles */ 
 control &sortvar;

run;
```

There is also a utility in the R package that performs serpentine sorting:

https://rdrr.io/github/adamMaier/samplingTools/man/serpentine.html

Does anyone know of a corresponding way to do it in python with Pandas?

Here was my best shot at it. It kind of works, but it breaks down after a few variables. I can never get it to match the output using one of the other methods above (PROC SURVEY SELECT, for example).

```
def serpentine_sort(testframe, classvar , isortvar):
    
    
    newframe=pandas.DataFrame(testframe)
    
    #create a list of true for each element in the list.
    #These will specify that
    ascenlist = [True for x in isortvar]
    
    
    
    # Perform an initial sort where we first sort by the class, and then the sort variables
    # in ascending order within the class
    newframe = newframe.sort_values(classvar, ascending=True) \
    .groupby(classvar, sort=True) \
    .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(isortvar, ascending=ascenlist)) \
    .reset_index(drop=True).copy(deep=True)
    
    
    
    
    
    ##### SERPENTINE SORT THE DATA ONE COLUMN AT A TIME                   #####
    ##### ==============================================                  #####
    ##### Create a sort variable that is a cumulative count within        #####
    ##### each group in the preceding variable. Use modulus division      #####
    ##### to reverse the count. If the count from the prior groping       #####
    ##### variable is 0, sort ascending, if the not, sort descending      #####
    
    
    grouplist = classvar
    for i in range(1, len(isortvar)):

        print ("Iteration: " , i )
        ranklist=[]
        ranklist.append(classvar[0])
        ranklist.append(isortvar[i-1])
        
        
        grouplist.append(isortvar[i-1])
        print (ranklist)
        print (grouplist)
        
        
        # Count the groups within the prior column within the class
        newframe["counter"] = newframe.groupby([isortvar[i-1]]).ngroup()
        
        newframe["serpvar"] = newframe.loc[ newframe["counter"] % 2 == 0 ].groupby(ranklist)[isortvar[i-1]].cumcount(ascending=True ) + 1
        newframe["t"]       = newframe.loc[ newframe["counter"] % 2 != 0 ].groupby(ranklist)[isortvar[i-1]].cumcount(ascending=False) + 1
        newframe.loc[ newframe["serpvar"].isna() , "serpvar" ] = newframe["t"]
        
        #print ("")
        #print ("Pre sorted")
        #print ("==========")
        #print ("")
        #print (newframe)
    
    
        newframe = newframe.groupby(grouplist, sort=False) \
        .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values("serpvar", ascending=[True])) \
        .reset_index(drop=True).copy(deep=True)
    
    
    return newframe



nscg=serpentine_sort(testframe=df, classvar=["BTHRGN"], isortvar=["AGEGRP", "WAPRI", "PRMBR"])
```

Notes:
the classvar argument is a grouping variable. Here I want to sort within groups. The isortvar argument is a list of my sort variables.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this example input similar to yours:

```
from itertools import product

cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['Low', 'Medium', 'High'], ordered=True)

df = (pd.DataFrame(product(['Low', 'Medium', 'High'], repeat=3), dtype=cat)
        .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Variable{x+1}')
     )
```

You could first sort in normal order, then compute the rank of each repeated value (by groups of self + columns of lower weight) and invert the odd ones, finally sort again after multiplying the odd values by -1:

```
cols = ['Variable1', 'Variable2', 'Variable3']

tmp =(df[cols]
 .sort_values(by=cols)
 .apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
)

order = (tmp.apply(lambda x: tmp.groupby(list(tmp.loc[:, x.name:]))
                                .cumcount().mod(2).mul(2).rsub(1))
            .mul(tmp).sort_values(by=cols).index
        )

out = df.reindex(order)
```

*Note: I am not sure how it generalizes to other datasets, feel free to update the question if you think that this doesn't fit all use cases.*

Output:

```
   Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
0        Low       Low       Low
1        Low       Low    Medium
2        Low       Low      High
5        Low    Medium      High
4        Low    Medium    Medium
3        Low    Medium       Low
6        Low      High       Low
7        Low      High    Medium
8        Low      High      High
17    Medium      High      High
16    Medium      High    Medium
15    Medium      High       Low
12    Medium    Medium       Low
13    Medium    Medium    Medium
14    Medium    Medium      High
11    Medium       Low      High
10    Medium       Low    Medium
9     Medium       Low       Low
18      High       Low       Low
19      High       Low    Medium
20      High       Low      High
23      High    Medium      High
22      High    Medium    Medium
21      High    Medium       Low
24      High      High       Low
25      High      High    Medium
26      High      High      High
```

Intermediates:

```
# tmp
    Variable1  Variable2  Variable3
0           0          0          0
1           0          0          1
2           0          0          2
3           0          1          0
4           0          1          1
5           0          1          2
6           0          2          0
7           0          2          1
8           0          2          2
9           1          0          0
10          1          0          1
11          1          0          2
12          1          1          0
13          1          1          1
14          1          1          2
15          1          2          0
16          1          2          1
17          1          2          2
18          2          0          0
19          2          0          1
20          2          0          2
21          2          1          0
22          2          1          1
23          2          1          2
24          2          2          0
25          2          2          1
26          2          2          2

# tmp.apply(lambda x: tmp.groupby(list(tmp.loc[:, x.name:]))
#                        .cumcount().mod(2).mul(2).rsub(1))
    Variable1  Variable2  Variable3
0           1          1          1
1           1          1          1
2           1          1          1
3           1          1         -1
4           1          1         -1
5           1          1         -1
6           1          1          1
7           1          1          1
8           1          1          1
9           1         -1         -1
10          1         -1         -1
11          1         -1         -1
12          1         -1          1
13          1         -1          1
14          1         -1          1
15          1         -1         -1
16          1         -1         -1
17          1         -1         -1
18          1          1          1
19          1          1          1
20          1          1          1
21          1          1         -1
22          1          1         -1
23          1          1         -1
24          1          1          1
25          1          1          1
26          1          1          1
```

Comment: This is an interesting implementation! Thanks so much for your insight. One question: what would you do if you wanted to do serpentine sorting within groups, or by a single group by variable?

Comment: @Sam define the columns to use in the sorting in `cols = […]`, it should (hopefully) work with any subset. If you want to sort groups classically, then wrap the sorting logic in a function and apply it per group with `reindex`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sort the data directly, create a “serpentine counter”. Then step through the counter and at each step pull any matching records from the input data and append them to the output data.

Example code can be found here: https://github.com/sgarrow/serpentine

Here is an excerpt of the relevant code and its associates output:

```py
def genSerpSearchCriteriaLst(minMaxLst):
    import math

    diffs       = [b-a+1 for a,b in minMaxLst]
    numToGen    = math.prod(diffs)
    should      = ['inc'] * len(minMaxLst)
    currVals    = [x[0] for x in minMaxLst]
    serpSrchLst = []

    while len(serpSrchLst) < numToGen:

        serpSrchLst.append(currVals[:]) # <-- the ':' fixed a bug.

        for idx in range(len(currVals)-1, -1, -1):
            if should[idx] == 'inc':
                currVals[idx] += 1
                if currVals[idx]  > minMaxLst[idx][1]:
                    currVals[idx] = minMaxLst[idx][1]
                    should[idx] = 'dec'
                    continue

            if should[idx] == 'dec':
                currVals[idx] -= 1
                if currVals[idx]  < minMaxLst[idx][0]:
                    currVals[idx] = minMaxLst[idx][0]
                    should[idx] = 'inc'
                    continue

            break

    print('\nminMaxLst = ')
    pp.pprint(minMaxLst)
    print('\nserpentine counter = ')
    pp.pprint(serpSrchLst)

    return serpSrchLst
```

```
Output:

minMaxLst =
[(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3)]

serpentine counter =
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [2, 2, 1],
 [2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 3],
 [2, 1, 3],
 [2, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: It's great to link to documentation, and the advice seems sound! It might help to excerpt the relevant code (re: making a counter) from the relevant script you linked to, though.